# How to download the grass style file in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

After using :style command to get the file, I can't edit it directly in the browser, or I can't download it. I have to copy and paste it to my local file, edit it and then upload again.

How can I download it?
Is it possible to edit it without downloading?

Answer (score 0):

You cant download it anymore as far as i know. Also you cant edit it in the browser itself. But you can still just copy it into your own *.grass and drag and drop it into the tab with the star.

Comment: What's the motivation for not allowing download? The best way is to be able to edit the file in the browser.

Comment: I dont know. Maybe they dont want to add all the things you could do with the style sheet. Also they dont want to confront newbies with writing their own style sheet. I also think so it would be way easier to just edit the nodes in the browser itself.